# Table "already exists" after dropping with if exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a pretty complex SQL that finally forced me to use a temp table to work around.

Essentially it looks like this:

```
;IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) LIKE 'dbo' AND name like '#MYTEMPTABLE')
DROP TABLE #MYTEMPTEBLE;

WITH cte AS ...
SELECT * INTO #MYTEMPTABLE FROM cte
SELECT * FROM #MYTEMPTABLE WHERE [conditions]
DROP TABLE #MYTEMPTABLE;
```

However, I get an error message saying an object with the name `#MYTEMPTABLE` already exists in the database after a call with an error (which is rather likely if the customer/tester screws up some data).

Comment: Unless you're running that query in `tempdb` then that `IF` will never be true. Temporary tables aren't created in the database you are connected in, they are created in `tempdb`.

Comment: @Larnu thanks, knowing the reason is really helpful for remembering the solution. I never knew they were created in tempdb.

Comment: The semicolon is a statement **terminator**. Use it consistently and you never need the lazy kludge of using it is a "beginator". Here it serves no purpose in front of the first statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might `DROP TABLE` fail on your check condition, it might check from `TempDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table instead of `sys.tables` table

```
SELECT * FROM TempDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN (
 SELECT NAME 
 FROM TempDB.SYS.TABLES 
 WHERE OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('TempDB.dbo.#MYTEMPTEBLE')
);
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1ff9fa5c461611b5b06321e3c7de7466)

If your SQL server version was higher than 2016, you can try to use `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #MYTEMPTEBLE;
WITH cte AS ...
SELECT * INTO #MYTEMPTABLE FROM cte
SELECT * FROM #MYTEMPTABLE WHERE [conditions]
```

if your SQL server version didn't support that, you can check `OBJECT_ID IS NOT NULL` which represnt temp table exists in your system

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#MYTEMPTEBLE') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #MYTEMPTEBLE;
```

Comment: Sadly, we are using SQL 2016 :( EDIT: But shouldn't it be IF EXISTS anyway instead of IF NOT EXISTS? It appears to work with that.

Comment: @Infrisios Ok I provide some different answers for you, and `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` support on sqlserver 2016